# POST request on GAE (status_code = 500)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

I am running the following code on Google App Engine Standard Python 2.7 version

```
import requests
import re
import datetime

ReviewsURL='https://play.google.com/store/getreviews'

payload =  { 'reviewType': '0'
                , 'pageNum': 0   #loads max 40 reviews for each page number
                , 'id': 'net.one97.paytm'
                , 'reviewSortOrder': '0'
                , 'xhr':'1'
           }

r = requests.post(
    url=ReviewsURL,
    data=payload,
    headers={
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            }
)

print r.text.encode('cp850', errors='replace').decode("unicode-escape")
```

This code used to run fine and output the latest 40 reviews but now it gives the following output:

```
Status_code = 500
```

When I run the same code on my Mac, it works fine as well.

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: I am not seeing any error in my logs. The 500 status_code is the output of the request above. I got it from the command r.status_code

Comment: I tried to get more information and below is the error I get when I print r.raise_for_status()     "HTTPError: 500 Server Error: None for url: https://play.google.com/store/getreviews"

Comment: How are you authenticating? Can you try to recreate the authentication? Taking into account that it was working at the beginning but then it stopped, authentication expiration might be causing the issue.

Comment: There is no authentication needed for this code to run

Comment: I followed up with Google Cloud support and they told me that the GAE IP is blocked for this website play.google.com/store/getreviews

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the message “Server Error: None for url” looks like the URL cannot get reached. 500 are mainly caused by 2 reasons:

1. [Dynamic responses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#response_limits), which are limited to 32MB. If a script handler generates a response larger than this limit, the server sends back an empty response with a 500 Internal Server Error status code.
2. [Exceeded response time](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#specifying_a_request_deadline). A request handler has a limited amount of time to generate and return a response to a request, typically around 60 seconds. There are several root causes listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors).

There are many reasons that can cause a response time exceeding. I expect that you find yours in the documentation. I am not able to guess one of them based on the information we have.

Comment: Thanks I followed up with Google Cloud support and they told me that the GAE IP is blocked for this website https://play.google.com/store/getreviews